# Asyncio Generator hangs forever when starting background task prior to yield

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

Why does the following async generator hang? I'm trying to start an HTTP call, yield the result of some work, and then get the result of that HTTP call.

This is the code that causes the generator to hang forever:

```
async def my_generator(items):
    for item in items:
        # start task before yield
        task = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(do_http_call(item))
        yield await do_work(item)
        task_result = await task  # <-- this line hangs forever
```

In this example, do_http_call and do_work are both asynchronous, non-blocking functions.

If I put both the starting of the task and getting the result of the task after the yield it works fine:

```
async def my_generator(items):
    for item in items:
        yield await do_work(item)
        # start task after yield
        task = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(do_http_call(item))
        task_result = await task
```

Comment: I don't see how either of those snippets can work. Both reference the variable `task_result` before setting it to a value.

Comment: I was trying to give some context as to why it was important to start the background task first, but since it's confusing I edited the question and removed it. (fwiw `task_result` is set to something outside the loop as an initial value)

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What do `do_work` and `do_http_call` do? What is `item`? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49037949/edit) your question to include a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So, what exactly happens when you run the first snippet? In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question to include more details. When iterating through the first snippet the program hangs forever. Specifically, it hangs on the `await task` line.

Comment: It's impossible to say what happens exactly without seeing what happens inside. Code you provide now doesn't seem to have any problems by itself. Only thing that comes to mind is that in the second snippet `do_work` may somehow change `item` that `do_http_call` wouldn't hang later.

Comment: What happens when you press `^C` while the program hangs? The resulting traceback should show where it got stuck.